# How to make sure multiple inputs each have a unique value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have six input boxes which will be updated dynamically. I want to force the user to have a unique number in each of the inputs before they can submit.

Below I have the following code;

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="10" class="check" />
<input type="text" value="8" class="check" />
<input type="text" value="9" class="check" />
<input type="text" value="10" class="check" />
<input type="text" value="12" class="check" />
<input type="text" value="11" class="check" />
<input type="submit" id="check" value="Submit">
```

JS:

```
var inputs = [];

function validateInput() {
  $(".check").each(function(i, elem) {
    if (inputs.hasOwnProperty(elem.value)) {
      inputs[elem.value] += 1;
    } else {
      inputs[elem.value] = 1;
    }
  });
}

$("#check").click(function() {
  validateInput();
  console.log(inputs)
  if (inputs.length <= 5) {
    console.log("fail")
  } else {
    console.log("success!")
  }
})
```

Currently `var inputs` outputs this in the console;

[8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 2, 11: 1, 12: 1]

I was hoping there would be a way for me to count the number of objects, so I could say if the number of objects is less or equal to 5 you have to go back and fix it, else if it's six you can proceed.

Hopefully this makes sense?

Hoping it's an easy fix!

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3v8hro0u/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object` to store key/value pairs . You can use `Object.keys().length` to get no. of properties present.

```js
var inputs = {};

function validateInput() {
  $(".check").each(function(i, elem) {
    if (inputs.hasOwnProperty(elem.value)) {
      inputs[elem.value] += 1;
    } else {
      inputs[elem.value] = 1;
    }
  });
}

$("#check").click(function() {
  validateInput();
  console.log(inputs)
  if (Object.keys(inputs).length <= 5) {
    console.log("fail")
  } else {
    console.log("success!")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="10" class="check" />
<input type="text" value="8" class="check" />
<input type="text" value="9" class="check" />
<input type="text" value="10" class="check" />
<input type="text" value="12" class="check" />
<input type="text" value="11" class="check" />
<input type="submit" id="check" value="Submit">
```

Comment: awesome thanks! and I guess the best way to clear the objects before is to just put inputs = {}; before the $(".check").each?

Comment: @Alex Using `inputs = {}; ` is assigning new `Object` to `inputs` . So, you will get a new empty `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Despite already answered, you can use a simple array, and add the value if not yet in the array. At the end compare number of items in array with number of inputs.

```
if (inputs.indexOf(elem.value) == -1) inputs.push(elem.value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ogonq5y/

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```js
$("#check").click(function()
{
 // store the values we come across
 var values = {};
 
 // count how many unique
 var countUnique = 0;
 
 // the inputs we want to check
 var checks = $(".check");
 
 // remove all error class
 checks.removeClass("error");
 
 // iterate through them
 checks.each(function(i, elem)
 {
  // if the value exists
  if(elem.value in values)
  {
   // set the error on the class on the current input
   $(elem).addClass("error");
   
   // and the error class on the first input we found with this value
   $(values[elem.value]).addClass("error");
  }
  // else
  else
  {
   // save it so we can modify it later if needed
   values[elem.value] = elem;
   ++countUnique;
  }
 });
 
 if(countUnique == checks.size())
 {
  // if they are equal then there were no dups
  alert("success");
 }
 else
 {
  // if they are not equal than there were duplicates
  alert("error");
 }
 
 // you could also count how many error classes
 if($(".check.error").size())
 {
  alert("error");
 }
 else
 {
  alert("success");
 }
});
```

```css
.error {
  background-color: #ffcccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="10" class="check" />
<input type="text" value="8" class="check" />
<input type="text" value="9" class="check" />
<input type="text" value="10" class="check" />
<input type="text" value="12" class="check" />
<input type="text" value="11" class="check" />
<input type="submit" id="check" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not JS expert by any means, So I probably have the incorrect syntax here, but I think what you want is something like this: (this will be more or less sudo code)

given your var inputs (which looks like a map):

```
listOfValues = inputs.values() //this gives you a list of all the values in HashMap (so it strips away the keys, the keys being 8, 9, 10, 11, and 12)
sum = 0
for(int a : listOfValues){ //idk the sytax but do a for each loop over the listOfValues
    sum = sum+a
}
return sum
```

so to walk you through it, inputs.values() gives you [1,1,2,1,1]
and then you use the foreach loop to add those values up. and obviously the sum equals 6.

I think thats what you were asking for but not sure

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach

```
function validateInput(callback) {
    var inputs = {};
    var result = 'success';

    $(".check").each(function(i, elem) {
        if (inputs.hasOwnProperty(elem.value)) {
            result = 'fail';
        } else {
            inputs[elem.value] = true;
        }
    });

    return result;
}

$("#check").click(function() {
    console.log(validateInput());
})
```